# FactoryGirl and Devise helpers not working in specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, factory-bot

Running rails 3.2.3 with guard/spork/rspec/factory_girl and have the following in my spec helper:

```
Spork.prefork do
  ...
  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
    config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
    ...
  end 
end
```

And have appropriate models/factories setup so that this should work:

```
describe "GET index" do
  describe "as logged in Person without Attendee record" do
    @person = create :person
    sign_in @person
    it "redirects to Attendee new page" do
      visit school_programs_root
      current_path.should == new_school_programs_attendees
    end 
  end 
end
```

However, when I run the spec I get:

```
Exception encountered: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `create' for #<Class:0x007f860825a798>>
```

When I change line 3 of the spec to:

```
@person = FactoryGirl.create :person
```

The factory is created, but I get:

```
Exception encountered: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `sign_in' for #<Class:0x007fcee4364b50>>
```

All this suggests to me that the helpers are not getting loaded for my controller specs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a known issue between Spork and FactoryGirl related to class reloading. The mechanism around this that I've used for years was once documented on the Spork Wiki, but has disappeard (why? -- it seems to still be necessary). It's still documented as a [FactoryGirl issue report on github](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/55#issuecomment-631787).

In brief:

In `Gemfile`, turn off the auto-requiring of FactoryGirl:

```
gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 3.5.0', require: false
```

In `spec_helper.rb`, in the `each_run` block, require FactoryGirl and include the Syntax Methods:

```
Spork.each_run do
  # This code will be run each time you run your specs.
  require 'factory_girl_rails'

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  end

end
```

This fixes the first error. On the second error, the Devise one, you need to run `sign_in` inside a `before` block, see below the fixes in your example. That should work for you.

```
describe "GET index" do
  describe "as logged in Person without Attendee record" do
    before do    
      @person = create :person
      sign_in @person
    end

    it "redirects to Attendee new page" do
      visit school_programs_root
      current_path.should == new_school_programs_attendees
    end 
  end 
end
```

Comment: I no longer have these tests in place, so cannot test your suggestion on my code. Thanks for contributing for anyone who may be able to use it in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Add to your spec:

```
include Devise::TestHelpers
```

Comment: Unfortunately not so simple; while it pushed past the sign_in error, it now becomes even [more bizarre](http://pastebin.com/ME302FrB)

Comment: I'm not sure, but what if you place sign_in to before :each do end block?

Comment: Didn't make a difference. I ended up just using the verbose syntax, and using a Cucumber feature to test instead. Thanks for your help.